# UI position differs from window size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a training project (Arkanoid). When bonus block is destroyed, the paddle is temporarily expended and this effect is illustrated by the timebar. The problem is timebar position. For some reason it depends on window size. Could you please help me to understand the reason of this problem and ways to solve it?

I adjusted its position for this case and it looks good:
[image: OK]

But when I maximize on play it appears in a strange position.

[image: not OK]

The timebar is instantiated by this code:

```
[SerializeField] TimeBar timeBar;

Instantiate(timeBar, timeBar.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, GameObject.Find("Game Canvas").transform);
```

So the position is set by `timeBar.transform.position` - as far as I know it means default position of the timeBar prefab.

P.S. timebar is a UI element and consists of UI text and UI image. May be the problem it connected with relationships between it and canvas?

Comment: I know you can use anchors when creating UI without code, but if you look up anchors through code, you could figure it out. Anchors are basically the scale point. If you scale the window, the anchor will always be in the same position which makes the UI work well. Here is a link t might be useful: [anchors through code](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1007886/how-to-set-the-new-unity-ui-rect-transform-anchor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to your Canvas in some way, yes, but mainly lies with the UI component you have not being anchored at all. As screen size can change quite drastically, to assure UI elements are relatively the same across all platforms and resolutions, anchor points are used. Think of them as a definitive point relative to screen size where an object will want to be.

[image: Anchor Points]
When selecting a UI object, the top of the inspector of this object should show a `RectTrasnform`, which has a square with a box and some arrows. This box is a visual representation of the anchor points of this object and how it will attempt to be placed when the screen resolution drastically changes from whatever you are using in the editor.

[image: Anchor Points Visual]

After clicking on this box, you will be met with a few different options. You are able to both set the anchor point, which is what you want as well as the position. I tend to anchor an object then move the position myself to a location I like. For your case, I would select the top-left anchor point, then drag it to a location relative to the top-left anchor you prefer.

Another issue could be how your `Canvas` is set up.

[image: Canvas Example]
I would make your UI set to `Scale with Screen Size` so the UI can auto-adjust itself to the new resolution, but keeps the anchor points you set. That way, your UI is dynamic. You can also set a goal resolution which is the resolution your UI assets or screen resolution is intended to be at. Along with this, you can tell the scalar how you would like it to attempt to fit to the screen by matching the width, matching the height, expanding or shrinking.